# How can I remove appointments to calender using long press

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a calendar app. I found and edited the code below to make an appointment. If I tap the calendar, I can make appointment. In addition, I want to remove appointments using long press, but I couldn't. (If you can think of another method, I would like to hear it.)

Example:
[image]

I want to delete red box.
This is code that I use:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

void main() => runApp(TappedAppointment());

class TappedAppointment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CalendarAppointment createState() => CalendarAppointment();
}

class CalendarAppointment extends State<TappedAppointment> {
  late CalendarDataSource _dataSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dataSource = _getDataSource();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SfCalendar(
            showNavigationArrow: true,
            view: CalendarView.week,
            firstDayOfWeek: 1,
            todayHighlightColor: Colors.red,
            timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
              startHour: 12,
              endHour: 24,),
            dataSource: _dataSource,
            onTap: calendarTapped,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void calendarTapped(CalendarTapDetails calendarTapDetails) {
    Appointment app = Appointment(
        startTime: calendarTapDetails.date!,
        endTime: calendarTapDetails.date!.add(Duration(hours: 1)),
        subject: 'Rezerv Edildi',
        color: Colors.red);
    _dataSource.appointments!.add(app);
    _dataSource.notifyListeners(
        CalendarDataSourceAction.add, <Appointment>[app]);
  }

  _DataSource _getDataSource() {
    List<Appointment> appointments = <Appointment>[];
    appointments.add(Appointment(
      startTime: DateTime.now(),
      endTime: DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 1)),
      subject: 'Rezerv Edildi',
      color: Colors.green,
    ));
    return _DataSource(appointments);
  }
}

class _DataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  _DataSource(List<Appointment> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SFCalender` has a callback for `onLongPress` actions where you can specify a function that gets called on a ´onLongPress´ event. With the `CalendarTapDetails` you can get a list of all appointments at this cell. Then you just remove those appointments from your `_dataSource`.

Here is an example:

```
void calendarTapped(CalendarTapDetails calendarTapDetails) {
   if (calendarTapDetails.targetElement==CalendarElement.agenda || 
     calendarTapDetails.targetElement==CalendarElement.appointment) {
       final Meeting appointment = calendarTapDetails.appointments[0];
       
       if (appointment != null) {
          _dataSource.appointments.removeAt(_dataSource.appointments
            .indexOf(appointment));
          _dataSource.notifyListeners(
            CalendarDataSourceAction.remove,
            <Meeting>[]..add(appoitnment));
       }
   }
}
```

Source:

Handling `onLongPress` action: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12121/how-to-handle-the-long-press-action-on-date-selection-in-the-flutter-calendar

And removing an appointment: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11522/how-to-delete-an-appointment-in-the-flutter-calendar

Comment: Thank you I understand and this answer helped me